# Make Description list alignment url

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am a big html/bootstrap noob so sorry for a stupid question.
I have a this html/bootstrap Description list alignment.
How do i mark it as a link, so its clickable?
Thanks
`<dt>Web</dt><dd class="personal_company_profile"></dd>`

Answer (score 0):

The main thing i get is that 'How to make  and  clickable?' I guess so. Anyways, just put anchor tag inside the .`<dt><a href="#">Web</a></dt>`. Try to use that.

Comment: Then my link will link to "personal_company_profile", instead of the link the class is containing. How do i fix that. `<dt>Web</dt><a href="personal_company_profile"><dd class="personal_company_profile"></dd></a>`